# Slow performance of query.reduce

Tags: mysql

i write the query using joins and inner query , query gives me proper result.but reduces the overall performance of my query.

inner query fetch maximum invoiceId amongst the clubbed invoice.

```
select sum(disp.noOfCases),inv.invoiceDate 
from outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration inv join outwarddispatchenteryregistration disp on inv.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId=disp.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId 
join ( 
select max(outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId) as outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId  from outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration  
group by outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId ) maxDateInvIdFrmMultiDispId on inv.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId=maxDateInvIdFrmMultiDispId.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId 
where inv.status=1 and inv.dispatchEnteryRegistrationStatus=1 and invoiceDate between :fromDate and :toDate group by inv.invoiceDate
```

How to convert this query so that it improves performance.

Comment: Might want to look into Indexing for your tables, it can improve the performance. Also, you might want to consider naming your tables a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery is missing the column  `outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId` ( without this your question should not work )

```
select sum(disp.noOfCases)
    ,inv.invoiceDate 
from outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration inv 
join outwarddispatchenteryregistration disp on inv.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId=disp.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId 
join ( 
    select outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId,
    max(outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId) as outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId  
    from outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration  
    group by outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId 
) maxDateInvIdFrmMultiDispId on inv.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId=maxDateInvIdFrmMultiDispId.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId 
where inv.status=1 and inv.dispatchEnteryRegistrationStatus=1 
and inv.invoiceDate between :fromDate and :toDate 
group by inv.invoiceDate
```

for performance  be sure you have proper index 
on table  outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration 
a composite index on

```
status, dispatchEnteryRegistrationStatus, invoiceDate, outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries can hurt performance (as effctively you need to join to them without an index).

Your query can be rewritten without a sub query:-

```
SELECT SUM(disp.noOfCases),
            inv.invoiceDate
FROM outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration inv
INNER JOINoutwarddispatchenteryregistration disp 
ON inv.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId = disp.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId
LEFT OUTER JOIN outwardorderinvoiceenteryregistration invmax
ON inv.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId = invmax.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId
AND inv.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId > invmax.outWardOrderInvoiceEnteryRegistrationId
WHERE inv.status=1
AND inv.dispatchEnteryRegistrationStatus=1
AND invoiceDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
AND invmax.outWardDispatchEnteryRegistrationId IS NULL
GROUP BY inv.invoiceDate
```